# Angular Template Not Showing with ng-hide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have an angular directive that I'm using to place a button form.  The template is hidden until the user needs to see it.  It's a simple template that works by itself, but when I combine it into the larger form the template does not appear.

Here is the directive:

```
.directive('buttonToggle', function() {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: {
                        myBtnArr: "="
                    },
                    template: '<button ng-click="click()">{{ myBtnTxt[myBtnArr] }}</button>',
                    link: function(scope) {
                        scope.myBtnTxt = ["AND", "OR", "NOT"];
                        scope.click = function() {
                            scope.myBtnArr = (scope.myBtnArr < 2 ? scope.myBtnArr + 1 : 0);
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
```

Then the html that works:

```
<div button-toggle my-btn-arr=0></div>
```

And the html snippet that doesn't work:

```
<tr ng-show="rowsShown >= 2"><td>Search by:</td><td><div button-toggle my-btn-arr=0></div><select ng-model="selection2" ng-options="option.text for option in options"></select><input type="text" size="20" ng-model="queryF2"><ng-md-icon icon="add_circle_outline" style="fill:#a9a9a9" ng-click="addSearchField();"></ng-md-icon> <ng-md-icon icon="remove_circle_outline" style="fill:#a9a9a9" ng-click="removeSearchField();"></ng-md-icon></td></tr>
```

When I run this html in the larger partial (which is controlled by a controller unrelated to the template) I get this error:

```
Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression '0' used with directive 'buttonToggle' is non-assignable!
```

So just wrap that template function in scope.$apply right?  Nope.  When I do that...

```
link: function(scope) {
            scope.myBtnTxt = ["AND", "OR", "NOT"];
            scope.click = function() {
                scope.$apply ( function() {
                    scope.myBtnArr = (scope.myBtnArr < 2 ? scope.myBtnArr + 1 : 0);
                })
            }
        }
```

I get this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

So it's obviously a problem with incorrectly wrapping the scope, but not sure how to fix it.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you don't want to create a two way binding for `my-btn-arr`. If you just want to pass data to the directive instead of bind to an existing variable, read from the attribute argument of `link`.

```
.directive('buttonToggle', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {},
      template: '<button ng-click="click()">{{ myBtnTxt[myBtnArr] }</button>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        scope.myBtnArr = attr.myBtnArr;
        scope.myBtnTxt = ["AND", "OR", "NOT"];
        scope.click = function() {
          scope.myBtnArr = (scope.myBtnArr < 2 ? scope.myBtnArr + 1 : 0);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

If you also want the possibility to pass a variable as input use `$parse`.

```
// This won't work with an isolated scope, inherit from parent scope instead
scope : true, 
link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
  // this will evaluate the expression against the scope
  scope.myBtnArr = $parse(attr.myBtnArr)(scope);
}
```

Now you can use the directive as

```
 <div button-toggle my-btn-arr="0"></div>
 <div button-toggle my-btn-arr="view.myValue"></div>
```

If you really want to use a two way binding, it must be possible to write values back into the path defined with the expression `my-btn-arr`. So, if you use `scope: { myBtnArr: "=" }` you have to use the directive with a writeable expression like this:

```
 <div button-toggle my-btn-arr="view.myValue"></div>
 <!-- "0" is not assignable-->
 <div button-toggle my-btn-arr="0"></div>
```

**Examples**: http://jsfiddle.net/Lw7ckt9x/1/

Comment: This was my guess as to where I might have been going wrong...let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: It worked!  And you're right, I only needed a one-way binding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using the link function, try doing the same thing under the controller function. Link function is required when you are doing any DOM manipulation for the functionality you require controller should be sufficient.

Comment: Just so I understand, I'm pretty sure I am doing DOM manipulation.  When the user clicks that button it's moving between three different states.  I also need for the number of the buttons added from this template to be flexible so the user can add as many as s/he needs.

Comment: Inside your click function you are just setting some state to myBtnArr, The DOM is changed by Angular. If you are doing some traditional DOM manipulation like finding control and setting its text stuff like this should be done in Link function. Here the button text is changed because of two way data binding which is supported by Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this error on the [ngdocs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign).

You use this:

```
<div button-toggle my-btn-arr=0></div>
```

but `0` is not assignable. Meaning you cannot do `0 = 1;`

You have to pass a variable with value of `0` instead of plain `0`
Like this:

```
<div button-toggle my-btn-arr="obj.myvar"></div>
```